# matlab matrix from array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have large array. Now I need a matrix with 8 elements in every row. My array looks like this:

```
    A= Columns 1 through 18

0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    0    0
```

Columns 19 through 36

```
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
```

and so on. How I can get [nx8] matrix? For example:

```
    B=[0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
       0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1
       0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
       0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0]
```

I've tried reshape, but it didn't work correctly. I get one 1 where shouldn't be.

```
    B=reshape(A,[],8)
```

Comment: 8*4 = 32, not 36. The sizes aren't compatible. You can do reshape(A,[4 9]) though

Comment: @Patrick I'm assuming that "and so on" means it end on a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about vec2mat 
[vec2mat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html)

```
 vec2mat(A,8)
```

Comment: Nice and simple! Why the f___ didn't I know about this function?

Comment: @chappjc: well, it's part of a not so common toolbox. So actually not a very general solution.

Comment: @thewaywewalk That's why. I've never used or seen the communications system toolbox.

Comment: @chappjc That toolbox also has the very interesting (and quite new to me also) `de2bi` and `bi2de`, which are like `dec2bin` and `bin2dec` but using numeric vectors instead of strings

Answer (score 6):

You almost have it. The problem is that Matlab fills the matrix column-wise, whereas you seem to want it filled row-rise. So create an 8-*row* matrix and then transpose:

```
reshape(A,8,[]).'
```